# I can not get true value when I use SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, sip, android-sharedpreferences

I am trying to use SharedPreferences to register account for my apps but it is always return different value from what I have saved at `saveSipAccount` in the first time when i try to get SharedPreferences at `getSipAccount` . It is only working when i restart my apps.
I am newbie for android and SIP so please help me, thank you so much!

This is my code

```
private static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "voip_demo_pref";
private static String SIP_DOMAIN_KEY = "sip_domain";
private static String SIP_PROXY_KEY = "proxy";
private static String SIP_USER_KEY = "user";
private static String SIP_PASSWORD_KEY = "password";

public void saveSipAccount(Context context, String domain, String proxy, String user, String password) {
    SipAccount account = new SipAccount(domain, proxy, user, password);
    saveSipAccount(context, account);
}

public void saveSipAccount(Context context, SipAccount account) {
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor e = pref.edit();
    e.putString(SIP_DOMAIN_KEY, account.getDomain());
    e.putString(SIP_PROXY_KEY, account.getProxy());
    e.putString(SIP_USER_KEY, account.getUser());
    e.putString(SIP_PASSWORD_KEY, encryptString(account.getPassword()));
    e.apply();
}

public SipAccount getSipAccount(Context context) {
    SipAccount account = new SipAccount();
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    account.setDomain(pref.getString(SIP_DOMAIN_KEY, ""));
    account.setProxy(pref.getString(SIP_PROXY_KEY, ""));
    account.setUser(pref.getString(SIP_USER_KEY, ""));
    String password = pref.getString(SIP_PASSWORD_KEY, "");
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        password = decryptString(password);
    }
    account.setPassword(password);

    return account;
}
```

and this is the code when I call `saveSipAccount`

```
String domain = String.valueOf(sipDomainView.getText());
        String proxy = String.valueOf(sipProxyView.getText());
        String user = String.valueOf(sipUserView.getText());
        String password = String.valueOf(sipPasswordView.getText());
       sipManager.saveSipAccount(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), domain, proxy, user, password);
        Log.d(TAG, "saved");

        try {
            service.changeAccount();
        }
```

and this is `getSipAccount`

```
public boolean changeAccount() {
    sipManager = SipManager.newInstance();
    SipAccount profile = sipManager.getSipAccount(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
    AccountConfig config = sipManager.getAccountConfig(app, profile.getDomain(), profile.getProxy()
            , profile.getUser(), profile.getPassword());
    try {
        MyApp.ep.libRegisterThread(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "libRegisterThread error.", e);
    }
    changeAccountStatus("processing");

    try {
        account.modify(config);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MyAccount.modify error.", e);
        changeAccountStatus("Fail registration");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you add this keys with question `SIP_DOMAIN_KEY` ,  `SIP_PROXY_KEY` , `SIP_PROXY_KEY` , `SIP_PROXY_KEY`,

Comment: "**in the first time when i try to get SharedPreferences at getSipAccount**" add you code when you are saving using **saveSipAccount** and when you are calling **getSipAccount**

Comment: Please, post whole class, where you use these methods.

Comment: I've add some code so please see it

Comment: In you above code **sipManager = SipManager.newInstance();** you are calling this after saving or before saving..?

Comment: I'm calling this after saving.

Comment: We can not help you until you post whole class. Not one method. Not two. Whole source code of this class, from the first line to the last.

Comment: Saving and retrieving above code should work, If you have correct getter setter in you **SipAccount** class, try to print the value before and after insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
`e.commit`()

and creat a String variable like this:

```
String str1 = pref.getString(SIP_DOMAIN_KEY, null)
```

and log str1 to check. Hope this help you

Comment: So you are not save your value with sharepreference successfull, you have to check before get value.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a special class for sharedPreferences. For example:

```
public class MySharedPreferences {

    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    public static final String KEY1 = "key1";
    public static final String KEY2 = "key2";
    // other keys

    private static MySharedPreferences mInstance;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private MySharedPreferences(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
    }

    public static synchronized MySharedPreferences getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MySharedPreferences(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    //this method will save the sip account
    public boolean saveSipAccount(String domain, String proxy, String user, String password) {
    SipAccount account = new SipAccount(domain, proxy, user, password);
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(YOUR_KEY, account.getDomain());
        //other putString
        return editor.commit();
}

public SipAccount getSipAccount() {
    SipAccount account = new SipAccount();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String domain = sharedPreferences.getString(YOUR_KEY, ""));
    account.setDomain(domain));
    //other code
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        password = decryptString(password);
    }
    account.setPassword(password);

    return account;
}
```

For obtain a SipAccount

```
SipAccount acount = MySharedPreferences.getInstance(context).getSipAccount();
```

Delete and reinstall your app.

Comment: String domain = String.valueOf(sipDomainView.getText()); and so on, check if this values is null.

Answer (score 0):

My apps worked when I used [Tray](https://github.com/grandcentrix/tray) instead of SharedPreference!
Thank you guy so much for your answer ad your kindness :) !